# What format should WAV files be for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using Audacity to convert my mp3 to wav for my cocos2d-x app, as mentioned in this article: https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/04/24/porting-cocos2d-x-games-to-windows-store-and-windows-phone/

I have two options:

> signed 16-bit PCM

or

> 32-bit float PCM

Which one is better for windows phone 8.1 ? The article does not mention which one to use, and I don't know enough about WAV to understand which is worse / better ..

Answer (score 1):

The quality difference between 16- and 32-bit WAV files is nearly never audible to the human ear on most sound equipment, and depending on the quality of the original MP3 will take up more space anyway.
Also, [not all](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11640) programs support 32-bit WAV's. I'm not familiar enough with Cocos2D myself to say, and a quick Google didn't turn anything up, but 16-bit is definitely the safe choice.